# jQuery multiple tabs UL acting as one

Tags: jquery

I have a page that has multiple tab groups however they are acting as independent groups where I would like them to be 'seen' as a single group. The reason is because I have 2 rows of tabs and I would like the content of those tabs to be under the row it belongs to which when active pushes down the second row of tabs.

Some HTML is:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#1">1 of 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">2 of 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">3 of 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4">4 of 8</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="1">1 content here</div>
<div id="2">2 content here</div>
<div id="3">3 content here</div>
<div id="4">4 content here</div>

<!-- Second row of tabs -->
<ul>
    <li><a href="#5">5 of 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#6">6 of 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#7">7 of 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#8">8 of 8</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="5">5 content here</div>
<div id="6">6 content here</div>
<div id="7">7 content here</div>
<div id="8">8 content here</div>
```

Any ideas?

Essentially it is the same as this http://jsfiddle.net/BLGUW/ but as you can see the first set of tabs 4,5,6 are separate to the second set of tabs 4,5,6 but I would like (if possible) both sets linked together but the content displayed as they are in the jsfiddle.

Comment: without seeing your css, or script is impossible to offer much help....create a demo in jsfiddle.net that presents overview of layout objective

Comment: What is the purpose of having the two rows "linked together"?  What behavior will change when they are "linked together" vs. when they are not "linked together"?

Comment: Row 1 content will be hidden when row 2 tabs are clicked and row 2 content hidden when row 1 tabs are clicked. Both rows belong to the same tab grouping but displayed in different parts of the page plus setting active class etc